# Django - CSRF verification failed using Google oauth2

Tags: python, django, google-api, csrf, google-oauth

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth
Im following the google tutorial to sign in and authenticate with a backend server, what im ultimately trying to do is restrict the access to the application to only the emails with the domain name of a company.
I think the problems lies in the javascript:

```
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://yourbackend.example.com/tokensignin');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
  };
```

heres the python part:

```
def autenticar_usuario(request):
# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)
CLIENT_ID="CLIENT_ID"
APPS_DOMAIN_NAME='example.com'
if request.method == 'POST':
    token = request.POST["idtoken"]
    try:
        idinfo = client.verify_id_token(token, CLIENT_ID)
        # If multiple clients access the backend server:
        if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID]:
            raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Unrecognized client.")
        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Wrong issuer.")
        if idinfo['hd'] != APPS_DOMAIN_NAME:
            raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Wrong hosted domain.")
    except crypt.AppIdentityError:
        # Invalid token
        userid = idinfo['sub']
return render(request, 'log_in.html')
```

and the error says:
'

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

'
html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html >
      <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Log In</title>      
      </head>
      <body>
       <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="">
       <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
       <script>
         function onSignIn(googleUser) {
         // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
         var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
         console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
         console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
         console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
         console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
         console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
         console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

         // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
         var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
         console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('POST', 'https://yourbackend.example.com/tokensignin');
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
         };
         xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
         };
       </script>
       <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script> 
    </body>
```

Comment: Show us the html page template that contains the login form.

Comment: there it is @JohnGordon

Comment: You aren't sending a CSRF token as part of the form submission.

Comment: i tried modifying:
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); to xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
do you know how to properly use both of them? @JohnGordon

Comment: Actually you are sending the token; I expected it to be called something else.  My mistake.